# Winform sql error

Tags: sql-server, winforms

I've got the following piece of code in a Windows form, but I'm getting an error

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'ExecuteNonQuery' accepts this number of arguments

I've searched around and everything I see seems to relate to the number of parameters. I'm supplying the number the code is expecting (43), can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
Public Class wfRecDB
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=RecDb;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;")      
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader

    Private Sub wfRecDB_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        cmd.Connection = cn
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCon_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCon.Click
        If cbEnv.Text <> "" Then
            cn.Open()
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into recdb.recs.recdbextract (Environment,Unreconciled,Reconciled,Account,AcctRel,AccInc,AcctPro,Address,AssClass,BankAcc,BrkRel,CBNwork,CCTE,CIB,ClCont,ClCparty,ClFatca,ClFatcaDet,ExtRef,FamGp,FundLd,GenVar,IsaDec,LocStr,MPLocPat,MPOutPat,MPPatDet,MPPatHead,MPProdPat,NomAcc,NomAccLink,OutAssCl,OutMktCam,SippAcc,SippBCE,SippBenReq,SippLta,SippPaye,SippPenInc,SippRegPay,UnitPrice,UserGroups,UserPerms) values ('" & cbEnv.Text & "','" & rbUnreconciled.Text & "','" & rbReconciled.Text & "','" & cbAccount.Text & "', '" & cbAccountRelationship.Text & " ','" & cbAccountIncomeDistributionChoice.Text & "','" & cbAccountProfile.Text & "','" & cbAddress.Text & "','" & cbAssetClassification.Text & "','" & cbBankAccount.Text & "','" & cbBrokerRelationship.Text & "','" & cbClientBroker.Text & "','" & cbClientCorp.Text & "','" & cbClientInd.Text & "','" & cbClientContext.Text & "','" & cbClientCparty.Text & "','" & cbClientFATCA.Text & "','" & cbClientFATCADetails.Text & "','" & cbExtRefPlfmOne.Text & "','" & cbFamilyGroups.Text & "','" & cbFundLoader.Text & "','" & cbGenericVariables.Text & "','" & cbIsadec.Text & "','" & cbLocationStructure.Text & "','" & cbtbMPLocation.Text & "','" & cbMPOut.Text & "','" & cbPatDet.Text & "','" & cbPatHead.Text & "','" & cbProd.Text & "','" & cbNomAcc.Text & "','" & cbNomAccLink.Text & "','" & cbAssetClassification.Text & "','" & cbOutCam.Text & "','" & cbSIPPAcc.Text & "','" & cbSIPPBCE.Text & "','" & cbSIPPBen.Text & "','" & cbSIPPLTA.Text & "','" & cbSIPPPAYE.Text & "','" & cbSIPPPen.Text & "','" & cbSIPPReg.Text & "','" & cbUnitPrice.Text & "','" & cbUserGroups.Text & "','" & cbUserPerm.Text & "')"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery("")
            cn.Close()
            cbEnv.Text = ""
            rbUnreconciled.Text = ""
            rbReconciled.Text = ""
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 3):

The error is very clear - there's no overload of `ExecuteNonQuery()` that takes a single **string parameter** as you're supplying here:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery("")
```

`ExecuteNonQuery()` expects **no parameters** - so just change that line of code to

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

and you should be fine.

Comment: @user5367782: excellent ! If this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.